# Python virtual environment suddenly lost all libraries and modules

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I was running Jupyter Notebook in my Python venv.

I made a new venv in a completely unrelated folder, but figured I don't need it. I move back to my original venv folder, ran my notebook files, just to find that **it lost Python3 AND ALL the modules and libraries** like numpy, matplotlib, beautifulSoup etc.

**Why and how does this happen?**

This is the code I use every time to my a virtual environment (provided by professor)

```
mkdir pyvenv
cd pyvenv
python3 -m venv `pwd`
```

And then to enter the venv,

```
source bin/activate
```

It seems that `source bin/activate` is [causing some trouble](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/2199506), but this article is a bit too hard for me to understand.

Plus, I have made separate virtual environments before so I am clueless as to why **this time** it just decided to get rid of Python3 and all other stuff in my original directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an environment, you only create that once (third line) and then you need to execute `source bin/activate` each time inside the directory. The problem you describe maybe is related with recreate the environment.